# in the range A1 to A70, if a cell is empty/blank then delete that entire row and move the other rows underneath up

Tags: excel, vba

in the range A1 to A70, if a cell is empty/blank then delete that entire row and move the other rows underneath up
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following codes.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicate()
On Error Resume Next
    Range("A1:A70").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

> ***Edit:***

```
Sub RemoveBlankRowsInARange()
Dim rng As Range, rws As Long, i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

'  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
'  rws = rng.Rows.Count
'
'  For i = rws To 1 Step (-1)


  For i = 100 To 1 Step (-1)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(i)) = 0 Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain this function:  SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

Comment: `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` means `blank` cells.

Comment: @Harum24HR Of the two answers, is there a way to check which is more efficient? is there a way to capture the time taken for the computer to carry out the task, the less time taken the more efficient?

Comment: There are some tools to measure that but I have no idea don't test yet.

Answer (score 0):

@Harun24HR - Here's how I attempted at solving this problem: I recorded a macro that deletes a row and I edited that macro to do my original question, why doesn't this work, please correct it:

Sub DeleteRowWithEmptyCell()

```
Dim row As Integer

For row = 1 To 100 'or whatever numbers needed
    If Cells(row, 1).Value() = "" Then
        Rows("row:row").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next row
```

End Sub

Comment: iteration when deleting needs to be done backwards. why looping at all?

Comment: @Thanh If you want to use loop then see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you.  Looping was my attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: @JvdV why does iteration needs to be done backward when deleting?

Comment: Deleting a row would shift up all rows, meaning you will skip the next row in a forward iteration.